# Scalable tile-based imageview for Android

Tags: android, pinchzoom

We have been looking for a suitable solution for a system we have in place. The solution we are looking for is a tile-based imageview that supports (pinch-)zooming and multiple detail levels. We are looking at tile-based zooming because our images are quite large, and there is a limit to the single Bitmap size Android can load.

**Desired result:**

The workflow is as follows:

- View is supplied with a total size (for the zoomed in image)
- View determines fitting detail level for initial display
- View displays visible tiles for detail level (level_row_col.png for instance)
- User can scroll and navigate the image, triggering drawing of new visible tiles and releasing of off-screen tiles
- User can zoom into and out of
  the image, triggering drawing of new detail level upon reaching
  certain thresholds. There is a maximum detail level to the tiles to
  save disk space, but upon reaching the maximum level the user is
  allowed to zoom in further without triggering further redraws.
- The
  original image is divided into square tiles of a certain size, with
  edge-tiles being potentially smaller. Each lesser detail level then
  does the same thing with the drawing at half size. For instance, an
  image of 2000x2000px would be made up of 8x8 256x256 square tiles at
  its most detailed level. The next detail level would contain 4x4
  (less detailed) 256x256 tiles etc.

**Current implementation and issues:**

Our current implementation uses a custom built two-dimensional scrollview which works fine on one detail level. The user can then click a button to zoom in or out. This creates an entirely new scollview with a new size and draws the tiles on the newly determined grid. The problem we are running into is that the initial view size is smaller than the original, because we want to initially fit the image on screen. If we then use the Scale property to zoom the view, the size doesn’t change which prevents us from drawing the more detailed tiles over the old ones at the new size, because each zoomed in level is larger than the last. This also prevents us from zooming in farther than the size of our original image, which is needed because of the detail in our images.

Our iOS implementation makes use of the CATiledLayer-functionality and functionality like the [TilingView](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Listings/Classes_TilingView_m.html)

Does anyone have any idea as to what kind of controls or solutions we can use?

Comment: i think your requirements are so specific that you need to create a [custom view](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) from the scratch...

Answer (score 0):

The library I used for a similar problem was [TileView](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView).

[image]

It is customizable, maintaned and is shipping with rich functionality.

You are free to provide your source of tiles (either from network, or from SD card).